# Order data frame and search by word

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using this code to extract some reviews when the word `Sony` is present in csv rows. Now I would like to know how to sort the search by the order of column id.

This is the csv structure

```
id review
#1 Some text ...
#2 Some text ...
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv('./file.csv', delimiter= '\t', lineterminator="\n")
print df[df['review\r'].str.contains("Sony")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df[df['review\r'].str.contains("Sony")].sort_values('id')
```

Comment: this  works fine for me .sort_values('id'). Why do you use subset word now?

Comment: It is same, I change it to original.